# Out-of-bounds writing does not always cause an error

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I wrote a function to add items to my log file. Variables `loglevs[]` and `des` together exceed 30 characters (by far). When I use the function as below, all works fine.

```
char *logitem (int loglev, const char *des) {

    extern const char *loglevs[];
    char *lld; // loglevel & description total 28 characters (7+1+20)

    lld = (char *) malloc((29) * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(lld, 29, "[%5s] %s", loglevs[loglev], des);

    return lld;

}
```

However when I use `malloc(24)` instead of `malloc(29)`, I get the following error:

```
root@vm:/home/geohei/devel# prog
*** Error in `prog': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000853330 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was expecting to get the error already at `malloc(28)`. Why is it only showing at `malloc(24)`? Actually, I can go down to `malloc(25)` before the error pops up.

I confirmed the test multiple times.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: So, in other words ... it is pure coincidence that it worked till 25 (included)?

Comment: Well... it is usually considered to be a lack of luck :)

Comment: I rephrased it to coincidence.

Comment: But basically, malloc(29) with subsequent snprintf(...29...) is correct? Confirm.

Comment: If wrong code failed every time, that would be far too convenient.

Comment: Good luck is when the program containing UB fails the first time it is run. Bad luck is when the first failure is when you are presenting the project.

Comment: Fine. Got the message. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking WHY, there are all kinds of reasons why something like this might work. They depend upon the implementation.

Your malloc function might allocate memory behind the scenes in fixed sizes or it could allocate memory that is already rounded up to some value. Let us say for example that your malloc implementation always allocated in multiples of 8 bytes.

Then, your malloc(25) — malloc (29) calls might actually be allocating 32 bytes. So going beyond the end, might not be hurting you. When you go down to malloc (24) you might be going right off the end of the memory block.

We can only guess what what is actually happening here. The library is free to do as it wants within the bounds of the language specification.

As noted, the behavior here is completely undefined which is why you should not do this. A different library might give an entirely different result.

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behaviour, which is defined in this [online c standard draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3) as follows:

> **3.4.3**
>
> **1 undefined behavior** behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous
>   program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International
>   Standard imposes no requirements
>
> 2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message).

So the program may do anything, even ignoring the situation. But it might also crash or call the police :-)

Comment: In the unlikely situation that it calls the police, what do you think it will tell them? :)

Comment: @machine_1: about an action of trespass probably :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB. `malloc` is just a standard library routine (which ask memory -in multiple of [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory))- to the kernel using some [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)). If you "overflow" the memory zone you have probably corrupted your heap memory.

But consider using tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (and [address sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) - e.g. [with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)).

Comment: Gonna have a look at it. Thanks!